# How to avoid grid lines to be removed in Detailed plot theme?

Tags: plotting

Hi guys I have the following equation that I want to plot.

```
pixx = k^2 Exp[-2 k^2 Sin[(t)/2]^2 ](-Sin[2t] - Sin[t](1-k^2 Sin[t]^2));
```

So I plotted as usual

```
i2k[i_] = 1/2 (i - 1)
xplt = 
 Plot[  Evaluate[
   Table[pixx /. k -> -i2k[i] /. t -> t - 2 , {i, 10, 80, 10}]], {t, 
   800 0.01, 840 0.01}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "Rotating frame, kx=20", 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time[s]", "pixx"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20], 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[Range[10, 80, 10], LegendLabel -> Style["k", 14],
      LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}], {.3, .8}], Frame -> True]
```

So the result is as follows

[image]

So obviously for a nice plot I need `FrameTicks`. Then I changed the code to

```
xplt = 
 Plot[  Evaluate[
   Table[pixx /. k -> -i2k[i] /. t -> t - 2 , {i, 10, 80, 10}]], {t, 
   800 0.01, 840 0.01}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "Rotating frame,kx=20", 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time[s]", "pixx"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20], 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[Range[10, 80, 10], LegendLabel -> Style["k", 14],
      LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}], {.3, .8}], Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{8, 8.1, 8.19, 8.3, 8.4}, {40, 20, 0, -20, -40}}]
```

Then the result is

[image]

However, the grid lines are eliminated which is not nice.

My question is how to use `FrameTicks` without eliminating the grid lines.

Comment: What is `i2k[i]`?

Comment: Ah, I am sorry, the code is edited.

Comment: Is this enough `GridLines -> {{8, 8.1, 8.19, 8.3, 8.4}, {40, 20, 0, -20, -40}}`?

Comment: Yes, I think that could be enough.

Comment: Try: `GridLines -> {Range[8, 8.4, 0.1], Range[-40, 40, 10]}`

Comment: Thanks, Kuba, it works.